# A proof by induction about composition series

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups

[image]

> In above lemma and proof, I can't understand how do we consider $G$ fixed. Because, I think that if $G$ fixed then, for proof's argument, if $G$ has composition series of length $n$, then it has to have *all* the composition series of length $1,2,\dots,n-1$; which may (and does) not hold.

This induction argument I can't digest, Please help.

(Note that I have yet to encounter Jordan-Holder, so can't use that to make my life easier.)

Comment: You are right, $G$ is not fixed. It is just sloppily written. As $|G|$ is finite it is easier to argue b y induction on $|G|$.

Answer (score 1):

The induction hypothesis is that the statement holds

> for every finite length solvable group having composition length $n$

and a solvable group $G$ having composition length $n+1$ is considered. If
$$
0=H_0\lhd H_1\lhd \dots\lhd H_n\lhd H_{n+1}=G
$$
is a composition series for $G$, then $H_n$ has composition length $n$ and the statement holds by induction hypothesis.